# Authenticating from a cross-platform mobile application consuming data from a WebApi service

Tags: authentication, azure, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, acs

I am trying to implement authenticating and identification on a [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) **cross-platform** mobile application consuming data from a WebApi service which I have.

My goal is as follows: 
Have the mobile application perform authentication against various [Identity Providers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_provider), get a security token, and have it passed to the WebApi Service inside the requests' headers. 
The service will then implement a `DelegatingHandler` to [validate the token](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stseverin/archive/2013/03/26/integration-test-for-aal-and-the-jwt-handler.aspx), and extract a userId from it, for later identification and authorization needs.
I would like my client code to be share-able as much as possible !

My options AFAIK are as follows:

1. Use [Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) to generate a federated security token on the client side, and validate the token on the WebApi service. I think it is possible, thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18263230/2126652). Code-Sharing on the client side looks promising, thanks to [Xamarin Azure Mobile Services Components](http://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-mobile-services/).
2. Use [Azure Access Control Service(ACS)](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/access-control/) to generate a federated security token on the client side, and validate the token on the WebApi service. However, I don't think that consuming the ACS on the client can be easily code-shared. Besides, ACS is not the new guy in town...
3. Use [Xamarin.Auth component](http://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth/) to have client side authentication directly against the Identity Providers, generate a JWT security token, and have it validated on the WebApi service. This should give more access to users' data from the IdP. However at the moment the component currently lacks Windows Phone support, and [It's not likely it will be available before late fall](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/24337#Comment_24337).

If anyone has already dealt with this scenario, please share your experience and let me know what would be the right way to go. 
If my goal is wrong in the first place, don't hesitate to criticize it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a Windows Azure Mobile Services (WAMS) backend at all? Looks like you have your own API which is unrelated to WAMS.

If you want to use WAMS just for their ability to give you a JWT and authenticate with Twitter/FB & Live (their supported IdPs), then you just need to use a token handler that knows how to deal with WAMS' token idiosyncrasies. ([This doc](http://docs.auth0.com/jwt) shows how they sign the JWT).

It is possible to use ACS, but they have a limited number of IdP too (albeit more than WAMS), and of course your API would have to consider a different token format.

You can take a look at our approach for this type of integration in this 2 tutorials we wrote. They are oriented towards our own identity platform, but the SDKs they use are open source and you can look at how they work (look for the links to the GitHub repository).

[Xamarin tutorial](https://docs.auth0.com/xamarin-tutorial)

[WebApi / MVC tutorial](https://docs.auth0.com/webapi)

A comment on your #3. Not all IdPs are capable of issuing JWT. You need an intermediary to generate that for you (e.g. ACS, a service like ours, etc). It is not a good idea to generate the token in the client code, because the client code is generally "not trusted". (and `secrets` are not stored in the device).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 1. I will use WAMS push notifications in the future. 2. WAMS supports Google as well. 3. Your approach looks interesting. Could you be please explain what are the advantages of this approach over using the simple Xamarin.Auth component (in respect to my specific scenario)?

Comment: #1 makes sense. #2 true. #3 Thanks. The Xamarin component above is actually built using X.Auth and I just posted it as an example. Likely similar to what you might end up doing (encapsulates URLs, gives you a User profile object, etc). Perhaps the sample more useful to you is the WebApi one, that you could tweak to accept the JWT in the format WAMS will generate.

Comment: As much as I have tried, I could not tweak the WebApi to accept JWTs from WAMS. Maybe you can help out? I asked [a separated SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273776/jwtsecuritytoken-exception-while-decoding-azure-mobile-services-jwt-token)?